# Subscribe infinite loop

Tags: angular

I'm trying to catch a BadRequest (400) while refreshing JWT token in `auth.interceptor.ts` because the refresh token should expire at some point. You can check the code snippet below but either I will provide StackBlitz too.

The problem comes from `catchError`, when I do `return this.authService.logout()` inside it. It runs into an infinite loop because when I do `return next.handle(request);` in the switchMap, it continues to `/api/values` (the actual request) that the user is not authorized for and it throws another error. Same goes for when I do `return throwError(error);`. This is where the infinite loop happens. I really have to subscribe to `this.authService.logout()` because after I log out the user, I'm revoking his refresh token from my database (HTTP post). You can see the entire code on StackBlitz.

```
return this.authService.refreshToken()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        console.log('Token refreshed.');
        return next.handle(this.attachTokenToRequest(request, token));
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return this.authService.logout()
          .pipe(
            switchMap(result => {
              console.log(result);
              return throwError(error); // request = /api/values, error = /api/refresh/token
              // return next.handle(request);
            })
          )
      })
    );
```

Except what's above, I tried to catch error code 400 with the code below but it's kinda the same.

```
if (error.status === 400 && error.error === "Cannot find that refresh token." || error.error === "Expired refresh token.") {
  console.log('400 bad request');
  return this.authService.logout()
    .pipe(
      switchMap(error => {
        return Observable.throw(error); // this should be replaced, maybe?
      })
    );
}
```

I know what the problem is as I've explained it above. What I don't know is how to solve it. I want to catch when the refresh token expires or it simply doesn't exist anymore and then log out the user and navigate to login page. How can I do that?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dziwbx

Comment: Use an 'if' and don't intercept the logout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your *logout* request to the back-end server bypass interceptors. So you create a new `HttpClient` using the `HttpBackend` and use that when you don't want your interceptors to interfere with the request.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
   private backendClient: HttpClient;

   public constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, handler: HttpBackend) {
      this.backendClient = new HttpClient(handler);
   }

   // this API uses interceptors
   public refreshToken() {
      return this.httpClient.get(....);
   }

   // this API does not use interceptors
   public logout() {
      return this.backendClient.get(....);
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome "hack"! Is that way recommended by professionals? I also wanted to suppress that 400 Bad Request error. Thus, I made catchError return `return next.handle(request);`, which removed the error message but there is a modal window from the HTTP Interceptor. I added headers skip functionality in the HTTP Interceptor but I don't know which request to add `HttpErrorInterceptorSkip, ''` to. Can you please check StackBlitz again for that issue and if everything else look okay? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dziwbx

Comment: @nop there is no `-1` status code for http client. A status code of `0` means that web browser could not complete the request, and there is no way of knowing if it was a connection issue, wifi issue, etc.. for security reasons.